# Possible with different Time frame sizes in Time Manager?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, timemanager

I have 5 polygon shapefiles from 2019, 2020, 2040, 2060 and 2080 (predicting a certain development). t_start is DateTime datatype (2019-01-01, 2020-01-02 etc.)

It works perfectly if I use the 4 layers for 2020-2080 and set the Time frame size to 20 years.

However, when I add the 2019-layer and keep Time frame size 20 years, I go 2019-2039-2059-2079-2099 (fair enough). And if I choose 1 year Time frame size it shows every single years from 2019 to 2080 (not very much happening 2021, 2022,...2039, 2041, 2042,... 2059 etc.)

I have been playing around with end time and accumulate, but without any luck so far.
[image]

I want to show 2019, 2020, 2040, 2060 and 2080 - combine Time frame size 1 year and 20 years. Is it somehow possible to set "unequal" time frames?

I'm using QGIS 3.12.0 and Time Manager 3.4.